# How to make 'spellfile' work for multiple languages?

Tags: spell-checking

I want to keep my Vim spelling synchronised across machines. For that reason I put my spelling file
into Dropbox by adding `set spellfile=$HOME/Dropbox/vim/spell/en.utf-8.add` to my *.vimrc*. It
worked just fine for a single language.

When I've added another spelling file for Ukrainian by changing `'spellfile'` value to

 `$HOME/Dropbox/vim/spell/en.utf-8.add,$HOME/Dropbox/vim/spell/uk.utf-8.add` it gets ignored. `zg` (with `:set spelllang=uk`)
adds a word to en.utf-8.add instead of uk.utf-8.add. Words are added to the correct file when
doing `2zg` but that's not what I want to do manually.

**How can I make Vim use correct spelling file based on `'spellang'` value?**

I've read Vim help on `'spellfile'` and it says:

> Normally one file is used for all regions, but you can add the region  name if you want to.  However, it will then only be used when
>     'spellfile' is set to it, for entries in 'spelllang' only files
>     without region name will be found.

Initialy I've thought it means regions like `en_us` `en_gb`. Do I misunderstand something?

Another even better option would be to change location /spell directory location to live outside .vim/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink) `~/.vim/spell` to `~/Dropbox/vim/spell`:

```
$ rmdir ~/.vim/spell
$ ln -s ~/Dropbox/vim/spell ~/.vim/spell
```

This will work on UNIX-like systems (Linux, BSD, OSX), for Windows, you can use:

```
$ mklink /D "$HOME\Dropbox\vim\spell" "$HOME\_vim\spell"
```

Comment: So simple and elegant solution! Only I'd rather `mkdir ~/Dropbox/vim && mv ~/.vim/spell ~/Dropbox/vim/` instead of `rmdir` :)

Comment: How does this solve having to do 2zg for the secondary language?

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple entries in `'spellfile'`, you have to supply a `[count]` to commands like `zg` to choose the correct target file.

A better approach is to make the `'spellfile'` entry always correspond to `'spelllang'`. So, set either

```
:set spelllang=en spellfile=$HOME/Dropbox/vim/spell/en.utf-8
```

*or*

```
:set spelllang=uk spellfile=$HOME/Dropbox/vim/spell/uk.utf-8
```

Because that is tedious, you can define custom commands or mappings:

```
:command! -bar SpellEn set spelllang=en spellfile=$HOME/Dropbox/vim/spell/en.utf-8
```

This would only not work if you have mixed-language documents. In that case, there's no way around defining both and using `[count]`.

Comment: That's strange to me that with `:set spellfile=<list of .add files in ~/.vim/spell>` Vim will work differently than if I would leave `'spellfile'` empty. Vim will work with exactly the same set of files but would threat them differently. Was it implemented this way intentionally with some specific use case in mind?